# Image upload from React to NodeJS, port connection refused

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello Dear Community :)

I'm trying to code an image upload on my website, from React to Backend in NodeJS.

I have this error with this port connection.

This path http://localhost:5000/api/plants with post method works fine in PostMan (with uploading picture). The problem occurs when I want to upload to the backend server.

[image: postman screenshot]

Here is the problem logged in the console

> xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5000/api/plants
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';




class UploadImg extends Component {

    state = {
        image: null,
    }

    handleChange = event => {

        this.setState({
            image: event.target.files[0],
            loaded: 0,
        })
    }

    handleFileUpload = event => {
        console.log('the new file upload is :', event.target.files[0]);
    }


    onClickHandler = (event) => {
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', this.state.image)

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/plants', data)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>New Thing</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileUpload} />
                    <button onClick={this.onClickHandler} type="submit">Upload</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default UploadImg
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-can-i-call-api-port-from-react-app-using-ip-address-but-not-when-i-use-localhost
TL;DR: replace localhost in the axios request to whatever your machine's IP address is.